# Can't get html to work with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jsfiddle

I have an issue, I have an code that I'm trying to get it to work on my website but can't. I have all necessary plugins in the code, but when I click on `deal` button, it won't deal any cards. However, it works fine on jsFiddle but not on my website.

```html
<html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>$MODULE_NAME$ - $SITE_NAME$</title>
 <?$META_DESCRIPTION$?>
 <?$META_KEYWORDS$?>
 <link type="text/css" rel="StyleSheet" href="/_st/my.css" />
 <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <input type="button" value="Deal Card" id="deal" />
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <div id='drop' class='drop'>Drop Here</div>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 $GLOBAL_BFOOTER$
<script src="http://joxongir.ucoz.com/cardgame.js"></script>
</html>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Is `cardgame.js` the file you're having problems with? This question need lots of edits.

Comment: I think so, i mean the html is there but i cannot seem to be able to execute js file. the link im trying to test in is joxongir.ucoz.com/stuff

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the domain to the lines that load jQuery and jQueryUI

Change:

```
 <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to:

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This works on JS fiddle because there the libraries are loaded for you automatically. At another location, you have to do it yourself>

Comment: In that case, are you using _Internet Explorer_ and getting a message about blocked content? Allow that content to run.

Comment: Actually, OP's way of including JS file is **better**! The browser uses the current protocol used, this is used for loading static files over SSL whenever available. Regardless this could be good if OP is testing locally and accessing the file over `file:////` protocol. Be careful out there!

Comment: Except the OP's code is not working. The best way to load js files depends very much under which environment the code is running. Since we don't have that information, grabbing the files over http from the original site is the best, one-size-fits-all method.

Comment: No, i made no changes at all. Can you please visit joxongir.ucoz.com/stuff and see if it works there, if it does work for you, then my internet connection is slow and maybe thats the cause of the issue

Comment: You are getting an error message about .draggable is not a function. I think you need newer versions of jQuery. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Removing line 71 _$(img).draggable();_ from cardgame.js gets the deal function working. Why are you trying to make this image draggable?

Comment: So i can drop the cards into a red box, once i drop the card, it should give me a message saying that it was dropped

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jQuery library and jQuery UI library file

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then include your code file

```
<script src="http://joxongir.ucoz.com/cardgame.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the jQuery library bofore you close the `body` and in your script use this to start the document:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // your code here
});
```

Comment: added the function both ways, in js file and in html, neither works

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not structured correctly. You closed your `<body>` and `<table>` tags after you've closed the `<html>` tag.

The proper structure:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, your jQuery `<script>` tags aren't written correctly. They should look like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```